# Why my debugging console is disabled in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sliding-window

So, i have solved this problem and I am trying to debug it and understand the workflow of the entire method for that specific output, so when I click on the debug icon by creating a breakpoint on first line of the method. I directly get the answer and debug console looks like this, step out and set into icons in it are disabled like this [image: this is the image]